# How can I render an ArrayBuffer (PNG image) directly as an image in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base64, png, arraybuffer

I'm getting a ArrayBuffer representing a PNG image file sent over a socket. Is there a way to render this directly to an image tab without needing to convert it to base64 first? It seems unnecessary to add the extra conversion step just for rendering.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert array buffer to blob and then use `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` to create a source to the image.

**Example**

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar2.png"


const App = () => {
  const [{
    srcBlob,
    srcDataUri
  }, setSrc] = useState({
    srcBlob: null,
    srcDataUri: null
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    let isUnmounted = false;
    
    fetch(url, {
    })
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then(blob => blob.arrayBuffer())
      .then(arrayBuffer => {

        if(isUnmounted) {
          return;
        }
        
        const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer])
        const srcBlob = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        
        setSrc(state => ({
          ...state,
          srcBlob
        }));
   
      })
    
    return () => {
      isUnmounted = true;
    }
    
  }, [])

return <div>
  {srcBlob && <div>
    <img width="100" height="100" src={srcBlob} alt="image blob"/>
    <div>Blob: {srcBlob}</div>
    </div>}
</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```